# Perl match file content using grep or read line by line

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a file with below content. Based on perticular condition I want to extract column1 data.

Input file:

```
RT0AC1 127.0.0.1
RT1AB1 127.0.0.1
RT2AC1 127.0.0.1
RT3AC3 127.0.0.1
ST1AC1 127.0.0.1
WA1RA1 127.0.0.1
WB1RQ1 127.0.0.1
WG3RA3 127.0.0.1
```

Data which is needed:

```
RT0AC1
RT2AC1
RT3AC3
ST1AC1
WA1RA1
WG3RA3
```

Here I have written a Perl script which can able to store the data in `$data`. But not able to write the data in `out_file.txt`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = system('grep "AC\|RA" file.txt  | awk -F" " \'{if((substr($1,4,2) == "AC")||(substr($1,4,2) == "RA")){print $1}}\'');

print $data;

my $file = "out_file.txt";
open my $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", $file or die "$file: $!";

print $fh $data;
close $fh;

#script continues..
```

The content of `out_file.txt` is blank. Am I doing anything wrong?

Do you suggest me to read the `file.txt` content line by line and match the content using `regex` and write the content to `out_file.txt` instead of searching using `grep`.

Which one would be faster?

**Edit**:

This is not my end of the script. I need to do further process in my script. So if you suggest perl one liner or `awk` I need to execute the way @toolic as suggested.

Comment: @toolic Cool. that works. What about the performance? Any suggestions.

Comment: `perl -ne "/^(\w{2}\d(AC|RA)\d)\b/ && print \"$1\n\"" file.txt > out_file.txt`

Comment: `perl -ne "/^(\S+)/ && print \"$1\n\"" file.txt > out_file.txt` -- if you need first column without any criteria.

Comment: I absolutely second the comment in glenn-jackman's answer about not calling `grep` and `awk` out of a Perl script, which is supremely capable of this kind of processing (as the answer shows).

Answer (score 3):

It's nonsensical to call out to grep and awk from perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @data;
open my $fin,  "<:encoding(utf8)", "file.txt";
while (<$fin>) {
    my $word = (split)[0];
    my $code = substr($word, 3, 2);
    push @data, $word if grep {$_ eq $code} qw(AC RA);
}
close $fin;

open my $fout, ">:encoding(utf8)", "out_file.txt";
print $fout join("\n", @data), "\n";
close $fout;
```

Comment: This nicely needs no regex, or one can do it all in regex: `my ($w, $c) = /(.{3}(AC|RA).)/; push @data, $w if $c;`, or even `if ( my ($w) = /(.{3}(AC|RA).)/ ) { push @data, $w }`.  I wonder how regex startup cost compares with `split`+`substr`+`grep` -- and, more importantly, how readability compares.  (Not a criticism, just wondering out loud.)

Comment: (That should've been `/(.{3}(?:AC|RA).)/` in the second case.  Also, one may want to replace the last `.` with `\S+`, or other more specific pattern, depending on problem specification)

Comment: @zdim Would you suggest me to use `split`+`substr`+`grep` instead of using `awk`+`grep` which I was mentioned in the question. Since this script is running each half an hour where input file is too lengthy. So I want to think about the script performance also.

Comment: @vinodk89  I'd absolutely suggest to do processing in Perl (and not call `awk`+`grep`) -- it is far better in every way.  For one, I'd expect that calling those external programs could only be _slower_ , as it incurs a lot of extra work. Time it.  But the important thing is that this is _better_ than carefully crafting a line that calls a complex combination of external tools. This is crystal clear, with far far fewer chances for errors, much easier to change when needed, more reliable ...